# Regular Expression - Spark scala DataSet

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I want to get tokens from tweets.

To achieve this I use RegexTokenizer of Spark 2.0 and scala. My problem is to achieve the pattern I want.

**I have these tweets:**

```
0) "#oscars https://w.r/123f5"
1) "#oscars! go leo!"
2) "#oscars: did it!"
```

**And I want to have the tokens:**

```
0) (#oscars, https://w.r/123f5)
1) (#oscars, go, leo)
2) (#oscars, did, it)
```

That is, if the tweet has word "#oscar." or  "#oscar!" or #oscar: ", I want the token to be:" #oscar "
At the same time if the tweet has word "leo!" or "it" I want the token to be:"leo" or "it".

**I don't want to disarm urls!**

I try :

```
val sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "#oscars https://w.r/123f5"),
  (1, "#oscars! go leo!"),
  (2, "#oscars: he did it! ")
)).toDF("label", "sentence")

val regextokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
  .setGaps(false)
  .setPattern("\\p{L}+")
  .setInputCol("text")
  .setOutputCol("words")

val regexTokenized = regexTokenizer.transform(sentenceDataFrame)
```

But it doesn't works well. I get:

```
(oscars, https, w, r, 123f5)
(oscars, go, leo)
(oscars, he, did, it)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `setPattern`, use

```
"(?U)\\bhttps?://\\S*|#?\\b\\w+\\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OZ6926/1).

**Details**: the regex matches URLs with `\\bhttps?://\\S*` and, with `#?\\b\\w+\\b`, hashtags or words.

- `(?U)` - make `\b` and `\w` to be Unicode aware
- `\\b` - a leading word boundary
- `https?` - `http` or `https`
- `://` - `://` literal char sequence
- `\\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace symbols
- `|` - or
- `#?` - 1 or 0 `#`s
- `\\b\\w+\\b` - a whole word, 1+ word chars (Unicode aware) within word boundaries.

Comment: How do I not separate the words like "i'm" or "haven't" ? I mean, now the regex give tokens like (i, m, haven, t)  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Change `\\b\\w+\\b` to `\\b\\w+(?:'\\w+)?\\b`. Same with hyphenated words - `\\b\\w+(?:['-]\\w+)?\\b`.